# Suggested Method of Converting Classic ASP Unordered List with Database Query to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, menu, sqldatasource

I'm working with a snippet of classic ASP code that sits in the menu section of a page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/articles/" title="Article">Articles</a>
    <%
        sSQL1 = "select zoneid, zonename from xlaANMzones where parentzoneid=0 order by zonename asc"
        rs.Open sSQL1,cnn,0,1
    %>
    <ul>
    <%while not rs.eof %>
    <li><a href="/articles/default.aspx?zoneid=<%=rs(0)%>" ><%=rs(1)%></a>
    <ul>
    <%
    sSQL2 = "select zoneid, zonename from xlaANMzones where parentzoneid="&rs(0)&"  order by zonename asc"
    rs1.Open sSQL2,cnn,0,1
    if not rs1.eof then
    while not rs1.eof 
    %>
    <li><a href="/articles/default.aspx?zoneid=<%=rs1(0)%>" ><%=rs1(1)%></a></li>
    <%
    rs1.movenext
    wend
    End if
    rs1.close
    %>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <%
        rs.movenext
        wend
        rs.close    
    %>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It appears that the zoneid and zone name from the database are being queried for the list of articles.  I need to convert this functionality into ASP.NET menu with flyout submenus.  Should I create a sitemap to connect to the ASP.NET menu?  Or, is there a more advisable way of successfully converting this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of recommendations:

- Create a web user control to render the list
- See if you can combine the queries into a single query
- Cache the query results, preferably with a SQL Server cache dependency
- Also look into caching the web user control itself

Comment: Should I attempt to merge the other unordered list of articles with this one?  Would a menu or treeview control be appropriate?

Comment: What other unordered list of articles? :) I meant you should reduce the number of queries sent to the database as much as possible, as it is usually a good place to optimize for performance. As for menu or treeview control, it really depends on your page design. There are thousands of nice jQuery menus out there, that uses nothing but an unordered list. But if your design lends itself more to one of the ASP.NET controls, you could just go for that...